# Taylor Series for Airy Functions

Tags: taylor-expansion, airy-functions

It is well known that
$$\operatorname{Ai}(z)=\sum
   _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^{3
   k}}{3^{2 k+\frac{2}{3}} k!
   \Gamma
   \left(k+\frac{2}{3}\right)}
   -\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{z^{3 k+1}}{3^{2
   k+\frac{4}{3}} k! \Gamma
   \left(k+\frac{4}{3}\right)}.$$

What are the steps to convert the above expression to the more concise form (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html)

$$\operatorname{Ai}(z)=\frac{1}{\pi 
   3^{2/3}}\sum
   _{k=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{ \Gamma
   \big(\frac{k+1}{3}\big)
   \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} (2
   \pi ) (k+1)\right) 
   \left(\sqrt[3]{3}
   z\right)^k}{k!} .$$

Comment: You have to look at the values of the $\sin$ function $k \text{ mod } 3$. So write the sum as $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {f(3k)}  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {f(3k + 1)}  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {f(3k + 2)} 
$$ and simplify.